# Break on error, but not on these specific lines?

Tags: javascript, debugging, exception, safari, webkit

I hope i am not alone in noticing that various versions of jQuery tend to have strange non-showstopper errors that get thrown but which are caught, and yet this tends to set off the debugger on Chrome and/or Safari in inconsistent ways even when the browsers are are set to "Break or Pause on uncaught exceptions".

It really should just not break there because these exceptions **do** get caught, as the console never gains the unsightly red error log, but like I said sometimes they pause the debugger there, and it costs me a few seconds each debug iteration to step past them.

It is strange and inconsistent, and I don't know whether it is the fault of Webkit, or Chrome/Safari, or jQuery code, but whichever it is, I don't have the resources to go wild goose chasing this one. I am working on my project today and currently Chrome `Version 27.0.1453.94 m` on Windows 7 is able to pass over these exceptions (when set to only pause on uncaught exceptions), but Safari `6.0.4 (8536.29.13)` on `10.8.3 (12D78)`, a rMBP 2012, still hangs up on them.

The exceptions are originating in `jquery-2.0.0b2.js` on lines `3668` and `3686`. I have definitely seen this happen before on 1.9.1 or 1.9.2 or 1.8.3 (it must have been one of those, i just don't remember which).

Is there a feature/extension that can let me specify "**anti-breakpoints**"?

Comment: I haven't noticed these pauses, unless I inadvertently set it to Break on All Exceptions. I usually use Chrome.